# Creating a Border with Different Measurements at Top, Bottom, and Sides

Tags: adobe-illustrator, borders

So I'm trying to recreate this plaque in Illustrator to have a replica made, but I'm a little stuck.  When creating the gold border around the oval, the measurements at the top/bottom are different than the sides.  The top/bottom are 3/8"H and the sides are 1/2"W.  How would I go about creating this border?  I am trying to avoid using the pen tool, considering the picture isn't straight on and it would just be a hassle.  Any help would be great!

Thank you! : )

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 2 ellipses and align them.

[image]

Or use an additional **Appearance Panel** Fill and then use `Effects > Distort & Transform > Transform` to alter the horizontal scale of the additional fill.

[image]

Or a much less precise way would be to use the **Width Tool** and alter a stroke profile (not the way I'd actually do this though - I'd use one of the methods above).

[image]